# Firefox WebAssembly specific performance issue in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: firefox, unreal-engine4, webassembly

I've been conducting some tests on WebAssembly and I am having a performance issue with an Unreal Engine based project, but it only occurs on Firefox. Chrome does not have this issue and so I'm trying to understand what the underlying reason for it may be.

This only occurs in one of the test projects which you can attempt to recreate here. In the image below, the top chart is firefox and chrome on the second chart. Each line represents a test with the two line groups representing two separate devices where the test has been run.

So my question is aimed at those familiar with browser implementations of WebAssembly and for what reason this might be occurring on Firefox. You can run the tests yourself here: http://kieranwarren.com/ue2/wasm/19/ship/PhysicsTest2-HTML5-Shipping.html and details on whether this can be recreated on your own devices would be appreciated.

X axis: Framerate
Y axis: Time

[image: Top: firefox, bottom: chrome]

Comment: WebAssembly is very new, and as a result none of the current browsers are highly optimised yet. You should expect to see quite a variation in performance.

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?component=JavaScript%20Engine&product=Core) about this? There seems to be a [huge metabug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/showdependencytree.cgi?id=1188259&hide_resolved=1) about WebAssembly development: it might be worthwhile checking for existing bugs there as well. Chances are you might be asked to get performance profiles to help devs figure out the bottleneck :)